# Django-Heroku-PostGres: KeyError: 'psql' during Git push Heroku main

Tags: django, postgresql, github, heroku

I'm trying to deploy my Django app in Heroku.  I'm also using PostGreSQL and Github.  I've been using a bunch of random tutorials to set this up and try to debug the results, so I apologize if there are "inconsistencies".

When I run `git push heroku main`, I get the error `remote: KeyError: 'psql' Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput`:

Here's the traceback.

```
remote: -----> $ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput
remote:        Traceback (most recent call last):
remote:          File "/tmp/build_e87847fa/manage.py", line 22, in <module>
remote:            main()
remote:          File "/tmp/build_e87847fa/manage.py", line 18, in main
remote:            execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 419, in execute_from_command_line  
remote:            utility.execute()
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute
remote:            settings.INSTALLED_APPS
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 82, in __getattr__
remote:            self._setup(name)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 69, in _setup
remote:            self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 170, in __init__
remote:            mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/importlib/__init__.py", line 127, in import_module
remote:            return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1030, in _gcd_import
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1007, in _find_and_load
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _find_and_load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 680, in _load_unlocked
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 790, in exec_module
remote:          File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 228, in _call_with_frames_removed
remote:          File "/tmp/build_e87847fa/medrec_project/settings.py", line 106, in <module>
remote:            DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600, ssl_require=True)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dj_database_url.py", line 55, in config
remote:            config = parse(s, engine, conn_max_age, ssl_require)
remote:          File "/app/.heroku/python/lib/python3.9/site-packages/dj_database_url.py", line 103, in parse
remote:            engine = SCHEMES[url.scheme] if engine is None else engine
remote:        KeyError: 'psql'
remote: 
remote:  !     Error while running '$ python manage.py collectstatic --noinput'.
remote:        See traceback above for details.
```

This is what I think is relevant from my settings file:

```
import os
import django_heroku
import dj_database_url
import psycopg2

DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2',
        'NAME': os.getenv('DB_NAME'),
        'USER': os.getenv('DB_USER'),
        'PASSWORD':os.getenv('DB_PASS'),
        'HOST': 'localhost',
        'PORT':'5432',
    }
}
DATABASES['default'] = dj_database_url.config(conn_max_age=600, ssl_require=True)

django_heroku.settings(locals())
```

The only place in my code that has `psql` is in my `.env` file:

```
SECRET_KEY='<mysecretkey>'
DATABASE_URL='psql://urser:un-githubbedpassword@127.0.0.1:8458/database'
SQLITE_URL='sqlite:///my-local-sqlite.db'
CACHE_URL='memcache://127.0.0.1:11211,127.0.0.1:11212,127.0.0.1:11213'
REDIS_URL='rediscache://127.0.0.1:6379/1?client_class=django_redis.client.DefaultClient&password=ungithubbed-secret'
DB_NAME='medrecapp'
DB_USER='<myusername>'
DB_PASS='<mypassword>'
DB_HOST='127.0.0.1'
```

When I run `py manage.py collectstatic` everything runs fine.

As far as I can tell, I've added PostGreSQL to PATH (points to the `bin` folder of PostGreSql).

I can use `psql` in my terminal without any problems

I can push changes to git without issues.

I've updated my Heroku Settings `Config Vars` with everything from my `.env` file.

Does anyone know how to solve this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

The solution is to change the address for postgres in the .env from 'psql://...' to 'pgsql://...'

in your case will be something like

`DATABASE_URL='pgsql://urser:un-githubbedpassword@127.0.0.1:8458/database'`

Knowing why it is happening is not necesary for this to work, but if you are interested... This is happening because dj_database_url at some point select the engine for the database based on the first word of DATABASE_URL.

Checking the SCHEMAS array we can see

`{'postgres': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgresql': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 'pgsql': 'django.db.backends.postgresql_psycopg2', 'postgis': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.postgis', 'mysql': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 'mysql2': 'django.db.backends.mysql', 'mysqlgis': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.mysql', 'mysql-connector': 'mysql.connector.django', 'mssql': 'sql_server.pyodbc', 'spatialite': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.spatialite', 'sqlite': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 'oracle': 'django.db.backends.oracle', 'oraclegis': 'django.contrib.gis.db.backends.oracle', 'redshift': 'django_redshift_backend'}`

they had entries for 'postgres', 'pgsql' and 'postgresql' but no for 'psql', that's why we got the 'KeyError' error.